# How to separate values of second table view in relation of clicked row of first table view?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview

i'm new to Swift and need your help.

In my app i have two view controllers. Both have a dynamic table view.
The first view controller and his table shows some categories (named Groups) and the second one shows some objects (named Single Groups) which belongs to these categories. The user can add and delete all content in both table views.
I'm saving the values from each table view in an array and using two entities in core data (one entity for each table view). In core data i save the ID of a category/object as UUID and the Title as a String. Also every UUID gets an index, so every value has its own place.

Now to my problem:

When I click on a row in first table view the next view controller (detailViewController) shows up. I can add some stuff and everything works fine.
But when I go back and click on an other row in first table view it shows the same things on detailViewController again.

So I think I have to separate the objects in second tableview for each row in first table view.
But i don't know how to do this.

What I thought about is to save the array from secondViewController in relation to the index of the rows value in first table view. The difficulty is that i separated all content from my app in different files. So Core Data has it own files as well as the storage with the arrays and the view controller itself.

[App Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv7DU.png)

Because of this I don't know what code you need exactly. I hope thats enough:

Class Group

```
import Foundation

class Group {
    private(set) var groupId    : UUID
    private(set) var groupTitle : String

    init(groupTitle: String) {
        self.groupId    = UUID()
        self.groupTitle = groupTitle
    }

    init(groupId: UUID, groupTitle: String) {
        self.groupId    = groupId
        self.groupTitle = groupTitle
    }
}
```

Class SingleGroup

```
import Foundation

class SingleGroup {
    private(set) var singleGroupId          : UUID
    private(set) var singleGroupName        : String
    private(set) var singleGroupAmount      : Double
    private(set) var singleGroupTimeStamp   : Int64


    init(singleGroupName: String, singleGroupAmount: Double, singleGroupTimeStamp: Int64) {
        self.singleGroupId          = UUID()
        self.singleGroupName        = singleGroupName
        self.singleGroupAmount      = singleGroupAmount
        self.singleGroupTimeStamp   = singleGroupTimeStamp
    }

    init(singleGroupId: UUID, singleGroupName: String, singleGroupAmount: Double, singleGroupTimeStamp: Int64) {
        self.singleGroupId          = singleGroupId
        self.singleGroupName        = singleGroupName
        self.singleGroupAmount      = singleGroupAmount
        self.singleGroupTimeStamp   = singleGroupTimeStamp
    }
}
```

Storage Groups

```
import CoreData

class Storage {
    static let storage : Storage = Storage()

    private var groupIndexToIdDict : [Int:UUID] = [:]
    private var currentIndex : Int = 0

    private(set) var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext
    private var managedContextHasBeenSet: Bool = false

    //need to init the ManageObjectContext, it will be overwritten when setManagedContext is called from the view controller
    init() {
        managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    }


    func setManagedContext(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
        self.managedContextHasBeenSet = true
        let groups = CoreDataHelper.readGroupsFromCoreData(fromManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
        currentIndex = CoreDataHelper.count
        for (index, group) in groups.enumerated() {
            groupIndexToIdDict[index] = group.groupId
        }
    }


    func addGroup(groupToBeAdded: Group) {
        if managedContextHasBeenSet {
            // add group UUID to the dictionary
            groupIndexToIdDict[currentIndex] = groupToBeAdded.groupId
            // call Core Data Helper to create the new group
            CoreDataHelper.createGroupInCoreData(groupToBeCreated: groupToBeAdded, intoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
            // increase index
            currentIndex += 1
        }
    }
```

Storage SingleGroup

```
import CoreData

class SingleGroupStorage {
    static let singleGroupStorage : SingleGroupStorage = SingleGroupStorage()

    private var singleGroupIndexToIdDict : [Int:UUID] = [:]
    private var currentIndex: Int = 0

    private(set) var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext
    private var managedContextHasBeenSet: Bool = false

    // need to init the ManagedObjectCOntext, it will be overwritten when setManagedContext is called from the view controller
    init() {
        managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    }

    func setManagedContext(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
        self.managedContextHasBeenSet = true
        let singleGroups = SingleGroupsCoreDataHelper.readSingleGroupsFromCoreData(fromManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
        currentIndex = SingleGroupsCoreDataHelper.countSingleGroup
        for (index, singleGroup) in singleGroups.enumerated() {
            singleGroupIndexToIdDict[index] = singleGroup.singleGroupId
        }
    }

    func addSingleGroup(singleGroupToBeAdded: SingleGroup) {
        if managedContextHasBeenSet {
            // add singlegroup UUID to the dictionary
            singleGroupIndexToIdDict[currentIndex] = singleGroupToBeAdded.singleGroupId
            // call Core Data Helper to create the new single group
            SingleGroupsCoreDataHelper.createSingleGroupInCoreData(singleGroupToBeCreated: singleGroupToBeAdded, intoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
            // increase index
            currentIndex += 1
        }
    }
```

Core Data Helper Groups

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataHelper {

    private(set) static var count : Int = 0

    static func createGroupInCoreData(groupToBeCreated: Group, intoManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {

        // create an entity and new group record
        let groupEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Groups", in: intoManagedObjectContext)!

        let newGroupToBeCreated = NSManagedObject(entity: groupEntity, insertInto: intoManagedObjectContext)
        newGroupToBeCreated.setValue(groupToBeCreated.groupId, forKey: "groupId")
        newGroupToBeCreated.setValue(groupToBeCreated.groupTitle, forKey: "groupTitle")

        do {
            try intoManagedObjectContext.save()
            count += 1
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save group. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }


    static func readGroupFromCoreData(groupIdToBeRead: UUID, fromManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Group? {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Groups")

        let groupIdPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "groupId = %@", groupIdToBeRead as CVarArg)
        fetchRequest.predicate = groupIdPredicate

        do {
            let fetchedGroupsFromCoreData = try fromManagedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            let groupManagedObjectToBeRead = fetchedGroupsFromCoreData[0] as! NSManagedObject
            return Group.init(
                groupId: groupManagedObjectToBeRead.value(forKey: "groupId") as! UUID,
                groupTitle: groupManagedObjectToBeRead.value(forKey: "groupTitle") as! String)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            // TODO error handling
            print("Could not read group. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Core Data Helper Single Groups

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class SingleGroupsCoreDataHelper {

    private(set) static var countSingleGroup : Int = 0

    static func createSingleGroupInCoreData(singleGroupToBeCreated: SingleGroup, intoManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {

        // create an entity and new single group record
        let singleGroupEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "SingleGroups", in: intoManagedObjectContext)!

        let newSingleGroupToBeCreated = NSManagedObject(entity: singleGroupEntity, insertInto: intoManagedObjectContext)
        newSingleGroupToBeCreated.setValue(singleGroupToBeCreated.singleGroupId, forKey: "singleGroupId")
        newSingleGroupToBeCreated.setValue(singleGroupToBeCreated.singleGroupName, forKey: "singleGroupName")
        newSingleGroupToBeCreated.setValue(singleGroupToBeCreated.singleGroupAmount, forKey: "singleGroupAmount")
        newSingleGroupToBeCreated.setValue(singleGroupToBeCreated.singleGroupTimeStamp, forKey: "singleGroupTimeStamp")

        do {
            try intoManagedObjectContext.save()
            countSingleGroup += 1
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save group. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }


    static func readSingleGroupFromCoreData(singleGroupIdToBeRead: UUID, fromManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> SingleGroup? {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "SingleGroups")

        let singleGroupIdPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "singleGroupId = %@", singleGroupIdToBeRead as CVarArg)
        fetchRequest.predicate = singleGroupIdPredicate

        do {
            let fetchedSingleGroupsFromCoreData = try fromManagedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            let singleGroupManagedObjectToBeRead = fetchedSingleGroupsFromCoreData[0] as! NSManagedObject
            return SingleGroup.init(
                singleGroupId: singleGroupManagedObjectToBeRead.value(forKey: "singleGroupId") as! UUID,
                singleGroupName: singleGroupManagedObjectToBeRead.value(forKey: "singleGroupName") as! String,
                singleGroupAmount: singleGroupManagedObjectToBeRead.value(forKey: "singleGroupAmount") as! Double,
                singleGroupTimeStamp: singleGroupManagedObjectToBeRead.value(forKey: "singleGroupTimeStamp") as! Int64)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            // TODO error handling
            print("Could not read single group. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

first Table View

```
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //    return fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // return objects.count
        return Storage.storage.count()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GroupsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! GroupsTableViewCell

        if let object = Storage.storage.readGroup(at: indexPath.row) {
            cell.groupTitleLabel!.text = object.groupTitle
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Segue to detailViewController

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetailSegue" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let navTitle = Storage.storage.readGroup(at: indexPath.row)
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.title = navTitle?.groupTitle
            }
        }
    }
```

Second Table View

```
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return objects.count
        return SingleGroupStorage.singleGroupStorage.countSingleGroup()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SingleGroupsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SingleGroupsTableViewCell

        if let object = SingleGroupStorage.singleGroupStorage.readSingleGroup(at: indexPath.row) {
            cell.singleGroupNameLabel!.text = object.singleGroupName
            cell.singleGroupAmountLabel!.text = String(format: "%.2f", object.singleGroupAmount)
            cell.singleGroupDateLabel!.text = DateHelper.convertDate(date: Date.init(seconds: object.singleGroupTimeStamp))
        }
        return cell
    }
```

I had searched for a solution a few weeks now but could not find anything.

Hope you could understand what my problem is and have any solutions or tips how to solve it.

Update:

Groups - read(at:)

```
    func readGroup(at: Int) -> Group? {
        if managedContextHasBeenSet {
            // check input index
            if at < 0 || at > currentIndex - 1 {
                // TODO error handling
                print("Can not read Groups.")
                return nil
            }
            // get group UUID from dictionary
            let groupUUID = groupIndexToIdDict[at]
            let groupReadFromCoreData: Group?
            groupReadFromCoreData = CoreDataHelper.readGroupFromCoreData(groupIdToBeRead: groupUUID!, fromManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
            return groupReadFromCoreData
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Same for Single Group

```
    func readSingleGroup(at: Int) -> SingleGroup? {
        if managedContextHasBeenSet {
            // check input index
            if at < 0 || at > currentIndex - 1 {
                // TODO error handling
                print("Can not read SingleGroups.")
                return nil
            }
            // get single group UUID from dicitionary
            let singleGroupUUID = singleGroupIndexToIdDict[at]
            let singleGroupReadFromCoreData: SingleGroup?
            singleGroupReadFromCoreData = SingleGroupsCoreDataHelper.readSingleGroupFromCoreData(singleGroupIdToBeRead: singleGroupUUID!, fromManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
            return singleGroupReadFromCoreData
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: You provided a lot of code but left out the most important method `readGroup(at:`. And please stop to use those horrible *objective-c-ish* ***private(set)*** variables. This is Swift! If you want constants declare constants, replace `private(set) var` with `let`. Further all the different singleton classes to manage the storage seem to be pretty expensive and cumbersome. Where did you get those from?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added the method for read(at:). The private(set) var thing i got from a tutorial, also the separation of all the classes. I'm at the beginning of learning Swift and so it seemed to be right. But i will change all the private(set) to a "let", thank you.

Comment: If I'm reading right, you're only trying to manage 2 data elements: some number of `Group` objects and, for each of those, some number of `SingleGroup`.  Normally that would be modeled in Core Data as a pair of classes with a one-to-many relationship between them.  You shouldn't need any data in those classes to manage them or their relationship...just the data your app wants to save/edit/show.

Comment: This seems to be a very helpful tip, thank you very much! I will do some practice in Core Data Relationships and try to implement it in my project.